# Dual OS, Xubuntu works, Windows 7 no internet, and black screen

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, windows-7, screen, ethernet

I'm having a similar problem.

I bought my Lenovo ThinkPad L450 without any OS installed. I first installed just Xubuntu without any trouble, all was working well including no trouble connecting to wireless internet. But then I decided to also install Windows 7. I managed to do that and was able to switch between the two. For some reason Windows 7 wasn't able to find any Ethernet drivers (Ethernet Controller was missing according to Windows). I tried to update Windows from CD, but then it made trouble, and now when I choose to boot with Windows, it gives me a black screen. I think I managed to hear the sound signal it makes to log me in when I just tried to write my password for logging in.

If I boot with Xubuntu, everything still works perfectly.

I'm considering reinstalling Windows, and give up Xubuntu. Maybe its causing the trouble for Windows.

Any ideas about what is happening in my situation?

Comment: Your assumption that Xubuntu is causing trouble is totally incorrect, anyways you can uninstall both, reinstall Windows, install driver for windows, and then install using Wubi. Also, this question is off topic here, [ask here](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) instead!

Comment: @SharadGautam Wubi has been discontinued years ago. And I doubt there is the need to basically start off from zero again.

Comment: Only if the OP tells what version of Xubuntu he has! @the_Seppi BTW I didn't know that, I have 14.0.4 which has WUBI.exe in the ISO, only the Wubi downloader has discontinued due to WIn 8 I guess!

Comment: @Vered Have you installed both in same drive, if so then maybe a permission or ownership problem!

Answer (score 1):

Whatever happened, I'm pretty sure it's unrelated to the installed Linux system. Missing drivers in Windows certainly are, the other thing I'm not quite sure about.

---

To analyse this problem, please use the Windows setup DVD to repair boot problems. This will make Xubuntu unbootable, but you can fix that later. Just make sure you have an Ubuntu live USB or CD/DVD (no matter which flavor) in order to be able to reinstall the GRUB boot loader if you decide to go back to Linux or dual booting.

If your Windows comes up without problems after using the boot repair utility from Windows' setup DVD, the problem seems to have been related to GRUB. If not, the problem is not related to the installed Xubuntu. In this case, please ask on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or a Windows/Microsoft forum for further help.

---

If you choose to keep on using Xubuntu, be it with or without Windows installed alongside, restore GRUB following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

PS: If you get your Windows back, you can download the necessary Ethernet drivers in Xubuntu, put the installer(s) on the Windows partition (or preferably a shared personal partition, if you made one), boot to Windows and install the drivers from there.